# combining multiple controllers into one view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter I have this *BuildTemplate function* in my **[HOME]** controller that authenticates a user. I have another controller called **[AJAXCONT]** that has a function called *search()* that returns data to populate my search table in the view. I would like to retrieve that controller's data from it's search function right after I generate the $top_bar_data view. How can I code this. Is my approach correct here?

```
private function BuildTemplate($view, $data) {

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in_faculty'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in_faculty');
     $top_bar_data['Firstname'] = $session_data['Firstname'];
     $top_bar_data['Lastname'] = $session_data['Lastname'];

     $master_data['f_top_bar'] = $this->load->view('f_top_bar', $top_bar_data, true);

          //I WANT TO RETURN ALL DATA IN THE AjaxCont controller returned by the search function HERE //

        //$search_data = (all data from my search function in AJAXCONT controller )
    // $master_data['search_results'] = $this->load->view('search_results',    $search_data, true);


   }

else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }

   return $this->load->view('master', $master_data, true);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move all your functions to models, controllers should only retrieve the data from the models and output it by loading views. CodeIgniter's controllers are only called by URI/Routing, you cannot call a controller or controllers methods from anywhere else.

Create a model to work with users, a second model that does what your search does. Then, from controller call those in the order you wish.